# Is there a way of updating a large form with checkboxes effectively?

Tags: php, checkbox

Having an issue updating a large form with checkboxes effectively to database.

Just for illustration:

```
<form action="save.php" method="post">
<?php
for {$i=0;$i<1000;$i++) {
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="product-' . $i . '">';
}
<input type="submit">
</form>


<?php
$posted_values = $_POST;
foreach($posted_values as $key=>$p) {
    $chkbox = $posted_values[$p];
    $update = 0;
    if ($chkbox == 'on') {
        $update = 1;
    }
   //Do some "expensive" checking for each posted value

   $save_dbarray[$key] = $update;
}

//Do the actual updating to databased based on array `save_dbarray`
```

Is there any way of just adding **changed** checkboxes to the save_dbarray? (Only checked boxes would be posted to $_POST, but I want unchecked values to be a part of the update as well if they have changed) I have to do some expensive checking for each posted value, therefore

**UPDATE**
I dont want to have loop through all 1000 checkboxes. I just want to loop through the changed (from checked to unchecked or from unchecked to checked) checkboxes, but in above case $`posted_values` would only return checkboxes that has checked values (from unchecked to checked)

```
<?php
//I DONT want to have to do like this:
for {$i=0;$i<1000;$i++) {
    $prodnr = 'product-' . $i;
    $chkbox = $_POST[$prodnr];
    $update = 0;
    if ($chkbox == 'on') {
        $update = 1;
    }
   //Do some "expensive" checking for every value

   $save_dbarray[$key] = $update;
}

//Do the actual updating to databased based on array `save_dbarray`
```

Comment: Can you explain your desired result more clearly?

Comment: Can you try javascript/jquery, like, `document.getElementById('product').checked`. also giving your checkbox name as an array (name='product[]') may be more easy

Comment: @arunrc - javascript/jquery has nothing to do with with my issue. nad yes, of course I could use arrays like product[] but my question is just to illustrate the issue Im having

Comment: Just an Idea. Keep the currently checked details in an array. Then after the update compare with the array to get the updated checkboxes. But the issue is you want to loop through all the checkboxes to find the update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [HTML array inputs and PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays) to do the same.

A sample code will be like below.

```
<form action="save.php" method="post">
<?php
for ($i=0;$i<1000;$i++) {
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="products[]" value="' . $i . '">&nbsp;'. $i .'<br>';
}
?>
<input type="submit">
</form>


<?php
print_r($_POST['products']); // Will contain your desired output
foreach($_POST['products'] as $i) {
    $save_dbarray[$i] = 'on'; // 'on' or whatever value if you need.

    // Actually you just need $_POST['products'], no need for this loop.
}

print_r($save_dbarray);
?>
```

**EDIT**

You need to loop through `$_POST['products']` to find the new checked ones and you need to loop through `$already_selected` to find the unchecked ones.

```
    <?php

    // Select from db or something
    $already_selected = array(2,3);

    foreach($_POST['products'] as $i) {
        if(!in_array($i,$already_selected)){
            $save_dbarray[$i] = 'checked_update';
        }
    }
    foreach($already_selected as $j) {
        if(!in_array($j,$_POST['products'])){
            $save_dbarray[$j] = 'unchecked_update';
        }
    }
    print_r($save_dbarray);

    // Do db update and select again and update $already_selected to display the checked ones
?>

<form action="save.php" method="post">
<?php
    for ($i=1;$i<10;$i++) {
        $checked = in_array($i, $already_selected) ? 'checked' : '';

        echo '<input type="checkbox" name="products[]" value="' . $i . '" ' . $checked . '>&nbsp;'. $i .'<br>';
    }
?>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: If I change a checked product to unchecked (from checked) that product wouldnt be included in $_POSTS['products'] ?

Comment: Yes, the best way is put a select query before this to find which all was already selected. If you really need it to pass it through form, put it in a hidden field in the form and pass it across on next submit.

Comment: Or, I update the answer with rather server side way, but again you need to select twice if you need to display already checked ones in the form.